# Can't get button to connect to javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm new to JavaScript and I was making a random quote generator but I can't seem to get my js code to link to the button. Is it something to do with my selectors?

```js
let quotes = ['The greatest glory in living lies not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall.', 'The way to get started is to quit talking and begin doing.', 'If life were predictable it would cease to be life, and be without flavor.', 'Life is what happens when youre busy making other plans.', 'Spread love everywhere you go. Let no one ever come to you without leaving happier.'];
let author = ['Nelson Mandela', 'Walt Disney', 'Eleanor Roosevelt', 'John Lennon', 'Mother Teresa'];
const quoteId = document.querySelector('.quote');
const authorId = document.querySelector('.source');
const btn = document.getElementById('loadQuote');


btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  quote.textContent = quotes[randomNum()];
  source.textContent = author[randomNum()];
});


function randomNum() {
  Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)
};
```

```html
<div id="quote-box">
  <p class="quote">You can do anything but not everything</p>
  <p class="source">David Allen<span class="citation">Making It All Work</span><span class="year">2009</span></p>
</div>
<button id="loadQuote">Show another quote</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `quote` in `quote.textContent`? Where does it come from? Running your code gives the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: quote is not defined"

Comment: The button is linked.

Comment: Are you referring to the p elements that have the same names on the HTML class attribute?

Comment: 1: Use the correct variables. If you name your variable `quoteId`, then don't call `textContent` on `quote`. 2: You are not returning the result from your `randomNum()` function. 3: You are calling `randomNum()` for both the quotes and the author, so the random indexes will not be the same.

Comment: it is supposed to randomize `citation` and `year`? if so where ?

Comment: I've taken the advice here but I am now faced with issue where the button works but does not display the quote or author, any ideas?

Comment: @Corse Have you fixed the second point in my last comment?

Comment: @Ivar yes though I don't think I fully understand what you mean by the 3rd point, but it won't even display any at all currently

Comment: @Ivar I have included a return at the end of the function yes

Comment: @Corse Only changing the variable names and adding return [_should_ show you quotes](https://jsfiddle.net/h2otwuvx/). But as I tried to say in my last comment, a different random number is picked for both the source and the quote, so the quote doesn't necessarily correspond with the source.

Comment: @Ivarf yes I done a stupid mistake and realised that my live server wasn't working therefore none of my updated code was being displayed, but yes I have realised this now and will try to come up with a solution to this myself to test my ability. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are different mistakes:

In named function you sould explicitly write "return" what you want to be returned by the functions,

Assuming "quote" and "author" are paired by their position, you should use a common "randNum" in the function passed in the event listener,

Other type error fixed.

```js
let quotes = [
  "The greatest glory in living lies not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall.",
  "The way to get started is to quit talking and begin doing.",
  "If life were predictable it would cease to be life, and be without flavor.",
  "Life is what happens when youre busy making other plans.",
  "Spread love everywhere you go. Let no one ever come to you without leaving happier.",
];
let author = [
  "Nelson Mandela",
  "Walt Disney",
  "Eleanor Roosevelt",
  "John Lennon",
  "Mother Teresa",
];
const quoteId = document.querySelector(".quote");
const authorId = document.querySelector(".source");
const btn = document.getElementById("loadQuote");

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let randNum = randomNum();
  quoteId.textContent = quotes[randNum];
  authorId.textContent = author[randNum];
});

function randomNum() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue many times in the past. You can do one of two things:

You can change the `btn.addEventListener('click', ...)` to `btn.onclick = function() { ... }`

Or, you can change `btn.addEventListener('click', ...)` to `btn.addEventListener('onclick')`

This happens because the 'click' function is run since it is a query of the button element. Imagine it like it is inside the button element where you would do `<button onclick="myFunction()"></button>`.